# How is 有在 different from just 在?

Tags: grammar, difference

I recently came across this phrase.

> 我平時**有在**運動。

Although this may be basic, I can’t seem to find any explanation for how this combination of 有 and 在 works grammatically. Most of the search results point to sentences where 有 is part of 沒有 and I have managed to find only a few affirmative sentences, such as the following:

> 我也**有在**向母親學習。

> 我現在**有在**吃藥。

My guess is that these are all talking about habits, rather than actions that are currently ongoing, but how is it different from just saying 在?

Comment: It's a Taiwan dialect usage.

Comment: There's a [*Grace Mandarin Chinese* video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqzbwCpLZl4), which discussed using 有 and 没有 in Taiwanese Mandarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put it in a right perspective to understand this:
有(in this case 有在) is an affirmative to a question: 你有没有 have you ever
whereas:
without the 有, it's just a statement of a fact.
more specifically, the difference btwn 我平时有在运动 vs 我平时运动 is：
the former usually is an answer to a question say of your check-up doctor: 你的体检大夫： 你平时有没有运动？whereas the latter: 我平时运动，周末休息。

now, 有在 vs 在：我有在运动 vs 我在运动
the second usually refers to "i'm working out now (so I'm busy and can't answer your call)", with 在 referring to an ongoing status.

in a nutshell: 有 goes in pair with 没有，有在 with 没有

BTW, 有在 is usually used with an accent on 有，in contrast to 没有 and is used more often among Southerners (incld Taiwanese) than in the North.

Answer (score 1):

"有" means existence, "在" means being, and "有在" means an action has been happening or is happening. For example, "我有在吃药" can mean that I have been taking medicine during the period of illness. Here, "有" emphasizes that the action has been happening continuously or intermittently. Another example: "我有在运动." The speaker indicates that he has been persisting in the behavior of exercising in the recent period. However "在"  indicating the continuous tense. For example: "我昨天八点在吃早饭." Then the action of having breakfast was happening at eight o'clock yesterday, which is the past continuous tense; another example: "我在吃早饭" This means that I am having breakfast now. It is the present continuous tense.